# Accessing objects being run by a thread-pool

Tags: java, multithreading, executors

For my program I was using a ConcurrentHashMap to hold references to multiple running objects.
In my server i have:

```
public class Server {

private ConcurrentHashMap<String, ChatRoom> _chatRooms;
private ExecutorService _chatRoomExecutor;
...

// create a new channel executor to handle 50 chatrooms
_chatRoomExecutor= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
// create an admin chatroom for testing at this point
_chatRooms.put("/admin", new Channel("/admin"));
// execute that chatroom
_chatRoomExecutor.execute(_chatRooms.get("/admin"));
```

would this work as I could still access the chatroom from the ConcurrentHashMap or would I have to do something with the threadpool?

Comment: This could work, I would make the fields `final` to ensure they don't change.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by "would this work" - would what work?

Comment: i didn't know if the references to the threads that the ConcurrentHashMap<String, ChatRoom> will hold, will change when I execute this line:
_chatRoomExecutor.execute(_chatRooms.get("/admin"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would this work as I could still access the chatroom from the ConcurrentHashMap or would I have to do something with the threadpool?

Yes your code should work fine.  **However**, you need to make sure that you are properly synchronizing on the fields in your `ChatRoom` objects since they will be accessed *both* from their `run()` method by the thread-pool threads as well as from the outside thread(s) by getting the objects from the `ConcurrentHashMap`.  That's going to be your challenge.

Comment: This might not be the best way to do this but all the chatroom object thread does is check if there is still someone in the room. If not it kills the thread. all the other chat room operations (ex. sending chats, having clients join/leave) are taken care of by an executor service that is contained with the chat room. all the other threads just submit their tasks to this executor service

Comment: I think that sounds like a fine architecture @ReCoNciLiaTiOn.